How do i can show a page in UWP Visual Basic dotNET?
i am trying to show a page (window) i created on my project
but when i try to run the app i see BC30456 'ShowDialog' is not a member of 'HelpPage'.
My question is: how i can show that page?
I tried with:
Dim helpWpage As New HelpPage
helpWpage.ShowDialog

and with:
Dim helpWpage As New HelpPage
helpWpage.Show

I'm new on UWP, i work with WPF and both methods worked on WPF, but in UWP, no.
Details:
SO: Windows 10 Pro
IDE: Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio 2019

You can use this code to navigate to that page:
Frame.Navigate(GetType(HelpPage))

This only works with pages, it doesn't works with ContentDialogs.

UWP page does not contain ShowDialog method, if you want to show dialog in UWP, you need to create ContentDialog instance and call ShowAsync method, for more information, please refer this document
And ContentDialog does not depend on the frame stack, it is modal page like ios system, you can show it anywhere on the page without frame stack. and if you do want to page ShowDialog method, you could make exension for the page class like following.
public async static void ShowDialog(this Page page)
 {
    ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog
    {
      Title = "No wifi connection",
      Content = "Check your connection and try again.",
      CloseButtonText = "OK"
    };

    ContentDialogResult result = await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
  }
}

Usage
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.ShowDialog();
}

